# Send a bean with html:link tag

Tags: jsp, struts

I wanna send an object(bean) using the tag as follows:

JSP:

```
  <logic:iterate id="demande" name="demandes">
            <html:link  page ="/show.do" paramId="demande" paramName="demande">
                <bean:write name="demande" property="demandeId" /><br>
            </html:link>
        </logic:iterate>
```

What can I do to retrieve the bean (demande) in the controller side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope your `demandes` from controller, then why you are trying send the same to controller again? If you need to send some particular iterated data then send any unique attribute like id(demandeId) to controller. I mean why object? I hope based on your unique id(demandeId) you can get the same object from your controller.

Updated Answer,

```
<html:link  page ="/show.do" paramId="demandeId" paramName="demandeId">
    <bean:write name="demande" property="demandeId" /><br>
</html:link>
```

Then in your controller,

```
Integer demandeId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("demandeId"));
```

Comment: Yeas my demandes are from controller, but Im not sending the same, I need to send the selected item or demand (singular), I need to send either the object or the id. The problem that I have came across is that I cant retrieve the object, I tried, in my controller, to do : request.getAttribute("demande");
 It sends null!

Comment: Instead of object send the `demandeid` to your controller. Based on that id you can create your object.

Comment: That works :)
My problem was that I'm using the wrong name for my variable, I thought it's gonna be: paramId, turned out that it's: paramName.
Thanks Vinoth Krishnan